# How to get output from Linux command via C/C++? and suitable for android?

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, android-ndk

I try to run a Linux command and read the output from it by using C/C++ code.
I search for exec but this don't deal with input/output.

What I am trying to achieve is to get information about wireless LAN by using this command `iwconfig`, invoking it from C/C++ code.

also i need a suitable code to use it as lib for android using NDK.

i see in android open source they called this function

what do you think about this code ?

```
int wpa_ctrl_request(struct wpa_ctrl *ctrl, const char *cmd, size_t cmd_len,
                 char *reply, size_t *reply_len,
                 void (*msg_cb)(char *msg, size_t len))
                {
        DWORD written;
        DWORD readlen = *reply_len;

if (!WriteFile(ctrl->pipe, cmd, cmd_len, &written, NULL))
    return -1;

if (!ReadFile(ctrl->pipe, reply, *reply_len, &readlen, NULL))
    return -1;
*reply_len = readlen;

return 0;
```

}

this is the  [link](http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/external/wpa_supplicant_6/wpa_supplicant/src/common/wpa_ctrl.c#505)

Comment: What do you mean by result? The output stream or the return code?

Comment: it wasn't invoked by C/C++ code, it's an either or. What command are you using to issue `iwconfig`? That would be the first place to see if you can get a returned value

Comment: the return value from the command, from my example the information of wireless lan .

Comment: You don't want the result, you want the output.

Comment: i don't know but i need the information return from this command @

Comment: ok i will do , but @g-makulik please see it

Comment: @DondonAli Show the code of what you're trying ...

Comment: @g-makulik , i have already post the code

Comment: Updated the question to say output instead of result.

Answer (score 3):

You could try running the command and outputting the results to a file, then reading it

```
system("iwconfig > temp.txt");
FILE *fp=fopen("temp.txt","w");
```

Comment: +1 Nice and simple solution (not to say `popen()` would achieve the same, but is more complicated to use) ...

Comment: fp will just be a FILE handle.  You can read it using fscanf() the way you would use scanf() normally.  I'd suggest you google for a basic C file reading tutorial

Comment: @DondonAli With `fp` you can read the string information from that file produced by the `"iwconfig > temp.txt"`call. You'll need to read it from the `fp` using `read()` (same for pipe file handle).

Comment: @g-makulik On the contrary, popen() is safer than system() and gives much better control. The only thing against, if anything, popen can be, popen is not part standard C. But I am a POSIX lover ;-)

Comment: @KingsIndian Of course! I'm trying to explain the principle to the OP!

Comment: There is a huge concurrency issue with this approach. Solving it properly would be more complicated than using `popen` so it is best to avoid this solution altogether. Just use the right tool for the job: `popen`

Comment: It's not the *correct* approach, no, but if @DondonAli just wants a quick and simple program for personal use, it should be just fine

Answer (score 0):

i see in android open source they called this function

what do you think about this code ?

```
int wpa_ctrl_request(struct wpa_ctrl *ctrl, const char *cmd, size_t cmd_len,
                     char *reply, size_t *reply_len,
                     void (*msg_cb)(char *msg, size_t len))
{
    DWORD written;
    DWORD readlen = *reply_len;

    if (!WriteFile(ctrl->pipe, cmd, cmd_len, &written, NULL))
        return -1;

    if (!ReadFile(ctrl->pipe, reply, *reply_len, &readlen, NULL))
        return -1;
    *reply_len = readlen;

    return 0;
}
```

this is the  [link](http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/external/wpa_supplicant_6/wpa_supplicant/src/common/wpa_ctrl.c#505)

Comment: Doesn't really tightly relate to what you've been asking. The key here is how to handle `ctrl->pipe` and how to retrieve (parsing) the information when reading the commands output from the pipe. To avoid downvotes, you'll be better off enclosing this sample to your question ...

Comment: if i use this answer 
system("iwconfig > temp.txt"); </br>
FILE *fp=fopen("temp.txt","w");

how to get string value from fp ?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour
yes i need this code to join it with android via NDK.

Comment: @DondonAli Well then this changes my vote for dup, also please edit the question to say that you are looking for an android solution.

Comment: _'if i use this answer system("iwconfig > temp.txt"); ...'_ For getting a string from a `FILE*` pointer refer to the [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fgets.html) function documentation.